# Searching a text in all directories

Tags: linux

I need to search "Ignoring request to authentication address " text in all the directories.What command need to give?

Comment: did you really try searching before asking this question?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`grep`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=grep&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en):

```
grep -R "Ignoring request to authentication address" .
```

Comment: If the search should skip binaries add `-I`. This will make `grep` even faster.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean "find all the files containing the text ...".

```
find . -exec grep -nH "Ignoring request to ..." \{\} \;
```

is one way and will output lines of the form

```
filename:linenumber:Ignoring request to ...
```

for each match.

The dot just after find in the command means "files anywhere beneath the *current* directory. You can put any directory here like /var/log if you have some idea where the files are, or even / if you want to search absolutely everywhere, which will take absolutely ages.

If you think the files have some kind of name like .log or .txt, you can start off

```
find . -name "*.log" -exec ...
```

to narrow it down a bit.